# C# - Iterate over resources in project

Tags: c#, resources

I am trying to iterate over the files in the embedded resource folder. The only way I found is to iterate over them and have the name of the file and its content but I do not want this.

I want to have the file itself so I can copy it as is to a local windows directory.

```
ResXResourceReader rsxr = new ResXResourceReader("Resources.resx");

// Iterate through the resources and display the contents to the console.
foreach (DictionaryEntry d in rsxr)
{
    Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(d.Key.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(d.Key.ToString() + ":\t" + d.Value.ToString());
}
```

This is the only way I saw in the internet but I need to have an object of the file itself.

Comment: What is the purpose of the call to `Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString` where you throw away the return value?

Comment: Isn't the resource file just the file named "Resources.resx"?

Comment: It is not really relevant just to show what I have tried, what is returned from this GetString is not what I need it is just the value within the file. I need to be able to have a File object or whatever to copy it directly to a directory in my local pc